# Duplicity Errno21 when restoring from external HD

Tags: restore, duplicity

I've just needed to reinstall Ubuntu due to some graphics driver error, but before doing it I backup whole home directory onto an external HD.

Now when trying to restore it with `deja-dup` I get info about not existing directory or having no access. That's why I used duplicity to directly restore it. I typed this command and got this:

```
kamil@kamil-K70IC:~$ duplicity file:///media/buffalo/home /home/kopia
Synchronizing remote metadata to local cache...
GnuPG passphrase: 
Copying duplicity-full-signatures.20120820T111049Z.sigtar.gpg to local cache.
[Errno 21] Is a directory: '/media/buffalo/home/duplicity-full-signatures.20120820T111049Z.sigtar.gpg'
```

Do you have any idea about what did I do wrong or if it's archive, which is broken?